# Picking path at random in DAG graph with probability equals to path weight.

Tags: probability, graph-theory, markov-process, sampling-theory, hidden-markov-models

I'm refering to the following paper: 
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.329.3653&rep=rep1&type=pdf.

There is a lemma states:

> Let $G$ be a directed acyclic graph with source $s$ and sink $t$. Let
>   each edge $e = (v_i, v_j)$ of $G$ have weight $w(e)$ (we also use the
>   notation $w(e) = w(v_i, v_j)$), and each node have weight $w(vi)$.
>   Assume without loss of generality that $$\sum_{all\ paths\ P=(v_1,...,v_{k(P)}) }{ w(v_1)\prod_{i=2}^{k(P)}{w(v_{i−1}, v_i)w(v_i) = 1} }$$
>   It is possible to pick at random a path $P$ consisting of $s = v_1, v_2,...,v_{k(P)} = t$ in time $O(n)$ such that $$Pr(picking\ P) = w(s)\prod_{i=2}^{k(P)} {w(v_{i−1}, v_i)w(v_i) }$$

The aim of the lemma is give a method for sampling in a HMM graph. The proof is by induction on the maximal lenght of a path between s and t.

My questions is:

Why assume that **all** path weight sum up to 1? and why without loss of generality?

I have thinked that only paths between $s$ and $t$ should sum up to 1. I guess that is related to the proof that is based on maximal leght of a path between $s$ and $t$ but how?

Comment: I am not too familiar with graph theory, so only posting this as a comment, but since the $w(v_i)$ are weights, iperhaps they are assuming that an appropriate 'scale-factor' can always be found so that the sum can be assumed to have any value and $1$ just happened to be convenient.

Comment: yes, but why sum for all paths?